# If two items are selected in 2 spinners, a image has to be displayed form drawable

Tags: android, spinner

Here 2 spinners are added . If i select particular item1 and item2 , a particular image has to be displayed . for example , if "Gujarat" and "Gandhinagr" are selected an image abc.png has to be displayed . Plz help me out.

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

private String[] INDIAN_STATE = { "Gujarat", "Andra Pradesh",
        "Arunachal Pradesh", "Assam", "Bihar", "Chhattisgarh", "Goa",
        "Haryana", "Himachal Pradesh", "Jammu and Kashmir", "Jharkhand",
        "Karnataka", "Kerala", "Madya Pradesh", "Maharashtra", "Manipur",
        "Meghalaya", "Mizoram", "Nagaland", "Orissa", "Punjab",
        "Rajasthan", "Sikkim", "Tamil Nadu", "Tripura", "Uttaranchal",
        "Uttar Pradesh", "West Bengal" };

private String[] INDIAN_STATE_CAPITAL = { "Gandhinagar", "Hyderabad",
        "Itangar", "Dispur", "Patna", "Raipur", "Panaji", "Chandigarh",
        "Shimla", "Srinagar and Jammu", "Ranchi", "Bangalore",
        "Thiruvananthapuram", "Bhopal", "Mumbai", "Imphal", "Shillong",
        "Aizawi", "Kohima", "Bhubaneshwar", "Chandigarh", "Jaipur",
        "Gangtok", "Chennai", "Agartala", "Dehradun", "Lucknow", "Kolkata"       };

Spinner spinnerState, spinnerCapital;
TextView tvState, tvCapital;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    System.out.println(INDIAN_STATE.length);
    System.out.println(INDIAN_STATE_CAPITAL.length);

    tvState = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mystate);
    tvCapital = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mystatescapital);

    spinnerState = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerstate);
    spinnerCapital = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnercapital);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_state = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, INDIAN_STATE);
    adapter_state
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerState.setAdapter(adapter_state);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_state_capital = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
            INDIAN_STATE_CAPITAL);
    adapter_state_capital
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerCapital.setAdapter(adapter_state_capital);

    spinnerState.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    spinnerCapital.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {

    spinnerState.setSelection(position);
    spinnerCapital.setSelection(position);

    String myState = (String) spinnerState.getSelectedItem();
    String myStatesCapital = (String) spinnerCapital.getSelectedItem();

    tvState.setText("My State is " + myState);
    tvCapital.setText("My State is " + myState + ".And its Capital is "
            + myStatesCapital);

}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the docs: 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html

I'm going to assume that there can be multiple capitals per state - otherwise, you don't need a capital spinner at all.

First, as per the above spinner docs, get rid of

```
spinnerState.setSelection(position);
spinnerCapital.setSelection(position);

String myState = (String) spinnerState.getSelectedItem();
String myStatesCapital = (String) spinnerCapital.getSelectedItem();
```

and just use

```
parent.getItemAtPosition(pos)
```

Then, add a call to the method you're going to use to display the photo. Here's some pseudo code for that

```
private Drawable getSelectedImage(String state, String capital){

    // Compare your selections here
    if(state.equals("Foo"){
        if(capital.equals("Bar"){
              //get and set appropriate image here
              int imageResource = R.drawable.foo_bar;
              return getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure your image files are added to the appropriate drawable folders.